# Why does my professor say that writing $\int \frac 1x \mathrm{d}x = \ln|x| + C$ is wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

My professor says that writing this is convenient
$$\int \frac 1x \mathrm{d}x = \ln|x| + C\tag{1}$$
but wrong, since it should be written as:
$$\int \frac 1x \mathrm{d}x = \begin{cases}\ln x + C &x > 0\quad(\star)\\[0.2em]
\ln(-x) + C &x < 0\end{cases}$$

I was wondering why is that the case. I thought that the two were equivalent, as one can see by the definition of absolute value.
In $(\star)$ the equality sign is dropped because the logarithm is not defined in $0$, but that would be the case with $(1)$ as well.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misunderstand something? Perhaps he wants antiderivatives defined in an interval?

Comment: @GitGud: I'm fairly sure he intended to say this. He even wrote it on the blackboard. Could it be that he made a mistake?

Comment: Notice that the integral only exists, if $0$ is not in the interval $[a,b]$

Comment: @Peter Well, the integrand only makes sense if $0$ is not there, so that doesn't add much.

Comment: @Peter: are you talking about definite integrals?

Comment: Yes, and in this case, you cannot simply use the antiderivate to calculate the integral.

Comment: Both ways are perfectly fine (and equivalent). My bet is that your teacher meant something else (if he did not make a mistake)

Comment: @Winther probably the posted answer from Ivo is what the teacher meant.

Comment: Yes, the formula $F(b)-F(a)$ gives a value here, but if $0$ is in the interval [a,b], the value is false because the integral does not exist.

Comment: But for intervals not containing $0$, you simply can use the antiderivate $ln|x|$

Comment: @TimSeguine If this is the case then this is teaching meant to confuse.

Comment: @Winther: Well he probably wrote two different constant and I didn't pay enough attention (the class is huge and I'm a bit far). Ivo's observation makes sense.

Comment: @Winther I disagree.

Comment: @rubik I agree that it makes sense that this is what he meant, but we cannot apply the integral over an interval that contains $0$ so this will never be an issue. Thats why I understand you were confused. I my opinion your definition is perfectly fine and there is no problem in using it.

Comment: but $\frac{1}{x}$ makes no sence for $x=0$

Comment: @Winther If we disregard the unfortunate indefinite integral notation for a moment, the point of the teacher most likely is that the family of primitives of $\frac{1}{x}$ on its domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is **not** $\log \lvert x\rvert + C$, but $\log \lvert x\rvert + C + D\cdot \operatorname{sgn} (x)$.

Comment: ask you Prof. for a counter example, everyone can say that your notation is not true

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right and I agree that this is likely what the teacher meant, but I feel its confusing to say that the students way of doing it is *wrong* (because of the indefinite nature of the integral notation)

Comment: hello, Daniel why do you write $\log|x|+C+D sgn(x)$ if $x>0$ we have $\log(x)+C+D=\log(x)+C'$ and if $x<0$ then we have $\log(-x)+C-D=\log(-x)+C''$ hm, i mean that is senceless

Comment: @Winther Well, IMO, using the notation $\int f(x)\,dx$ is already wrong. But if you use it to denote the family of primitives of $f$, then it is wrong to say that the family is $\{ \log \lvert x\rvert + C : C\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Using $D\cdot \operatorname{sgn} (x)$ is just a convenient way to avoid writing the case distinction here in the comments.

Comment: @DanielFischer IMO I think we should be careful about using the word *wrong* about something that is a minor detail (and to a student learning about integration for the first time this *is* a minor detail).

Comment: Related discussion: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/03/reader_survey_logx_c.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with what you wrote there. I could only imagine a rigorous teacher commenting about the constant... it need not be the same in each interval, as in: $$\int \frac 1x \mathrm{d}x = \begin{cases}\ln x + C_1 &x > 0\\[0.2em]
\ln(-x) + C_2 &x < 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ah! Maybe this is the reason. It does make sense.

Answer (score 9):

The notation $\int \frac 1x dx$ is already ambiguous. If $f$ is defined on some open set of the real numbers, the notation 
$$ \int f(x) dx = RHS$$
(without borns of integration) means that the primitives on $f$ in its open set of definition are the functions that are parametrized by the RHS.

If $f$ is defined on an inverval, this simply gives 
$$ \int f(x)dx = F(x) + C, C \in \mathbb{R}.$$
If $f$ is defined on a union of disjoint intervals, then you should be more precised. In my opinion, it is better in this case to write a sentence of the kind:

The primitives of $\frac 1x$ on $\mathbb{R}^\ast$ are the functions defined by $\ln(-x) + C_1$ for $x < 0$ and $\ln(x) + C_2$ for $x > 0$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary real constants.